# How to return the array of strings?

Tags: c, string, random

I have to return the array b to the main program as char **. How do I do it? If I give

```
return b;
```

it gives me an error.

In main() if I give

```
char **c;
c=GetRandomStrings(2,10,10);
```

I will get the first string. How to obtain the remaining strings?

```
char b[10][20];

char**  GetRandomStrings(int minimumLengthOfString, int maximumLengthOfString, int numOfStrings)
{
    static const char alphanum[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char s[maximumLengthOfString];
    int num =0,length;

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    for (int j=0;j<numOfStrings;j++)
    {
        length = randomLength (minimumLengthOfString,maximumLengthOfString);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        {
            num = rand() % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1);
            s[i] = alphanum[num];
        }

       s[length] = '\0';
       strcpy(b[j],s);
    }

    for (int j=0;j<numOfStrings;j++)
    {
       printf("\n\n%s",b[j]);
    }
    return b;
}

int randomLength(int minimumLength, int maximumLength)
{
    return (rand()%(maximumLength - minimumLength) + minimumLength);
}
```

Comment: Well you're not actually returning anything?

Comment: Besides that, if you intend to return `b`, then consider that you will return a pointer to a local variable, which leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and also that `b` is an array of arrays of characters, which is *not* the same as a pointer to a pointer to character.

Comment: `b` should not be global, you should `malloc` it within `GetRandomStrings()`

Comment: type of `b` is `char (*)[20]`, not `char**`. but There is no need to return a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to return `b` from your function you will get warning such as-

```
warning: return from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
warning: function returns address of local variable [enabled by default]
```

Which leads to undefined behavior!

Try to make `b` as a pointer to pointer to character and allocate memory for it, Get the strings and return the address of `b`. This time when you leave the function `b` wont get affected.

And finally don't forget to free the allocated memory!